# Add xml-stylesheet processing instructions to boost property_tree

Tags: c++, xml, boost-propertytree

I am using boost/property_tree to create an XML file. 
Unfortunately I cannot figure out how to add xml-stylesheet processing instructions to the file.

Desirable output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <-- This is added automatically
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="report.xsl"?> <-- How to add this line
<report>
...
</report>
```

Is that possible with boost/property_tree/ptree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that boost/property_tree xml writer doesn't have a support for xml stylesheets processing instructions. First line (xml version) is  simply hardcoded in the write_xml_internal function.

So I've just written my own write xml function, which is doing exactly the same, plus adds xml stylesheet.

```
void WriteXML(std::ostream &output, ptree &root)
{
 boost::property_tree::xml_writer_settings<char> settings('\t', 1);

 output << "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"";
 output << settings.encoding;
 output << "\"?>\n";
 output << "<?xml-stylesheet type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"report.xsl\"?>\n";

 write_xml_element(output, std::basic_string<ptree::key_type::value_type>(), root, -1, settings);
}
```

Comment: Note that `write_xml_element` is [not part of the documented implementation API](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/property_tree/reference.html#header.boost.property_tree.xml_parser_hpp) and maybe subject to change or not do what you expect always. Sweet hack though. +1

Answer (score 2):

My hack is to use the writer settings:

```
boost::property_tree::xml_writer_settings<char> settings('\t', 1, "utf-8\"?>\n<?xml-stylesheet type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"report.xsl");
boost::property_tree::write_xml(yourAbsolutePath, yourPropertyTree, std::locale(), settings);
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="report.xsl"?>
```