# XML version and encoding from boost ptree

Tags: c++, boost, boost-propertytree

I am using boost ptree to parse xml

```
read_xml(stream, pt, trim_whitespace | no_comments);



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<rss>  
<channel>.....</channel> 
</rss>
```

How to read the version and encoding of the xml :
I tried the following

```
std::string encoding =  pt.get<std::string>("<xmlattr>.encoding", "");
```

which gives empty string.
How to get the version and encoding of xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The processing instruction is not an XML element (in fact, it's... a processing instruction).

Processing instructions do not have attributes in the `<xmlattr>` sense. You will note that there is no ptree node corresponding to it.

Here's an undocumented way to achieve what you likely want: [Add xml-stylesheet processing instructions to boost property_tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12805633/add-xml-stylesheet-processing-instructions-to-boost-property-tree/12846962#12846962)

Comment: Thanks @sehe, but i think xml_writer_setting always return **utf-8** as encoding  [boost xml witer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/boost/property_tree/detail/xml_parser_writer_settings.hpp), doesn't it?

Comment: Basically, what you're discovering is that Boost doesn't have an XML library.